# Rpy2, use of scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)

Tags: python, rpy2

I'm not able to figure out how to use the ggplot2 option `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)` inside rpy2.

Example code:

```
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
base = importr('base')

mtcars = data(datasets).fetch('mtcars')['mtcars']

gp = ggplot2.ggplot(mtcars)

pp = gp + \
     ggplot2.aes_string(x='wt', y='mpg') + \
     ggplot2.geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(labels = ggplot2.percent)

pp.plot()
```

That raises:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'percent'
```

**SOLUTION**

```
scales = importr("scales")
[..some plot code here..]
.. + ggplot2.scale_y_continuous(labels = scales.percent_format())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because either that symbol is not in the namespace for the R package `ggplot2`.

```
scales = importr('scales')
scales.percent
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'InstalledSTPackage' object has no attribute 'percent'`

Comment: Because `percent` is not in `ggplot2`. Answer fixed.